# What is the point of using onion alternatives for clearnet websites when using tor?

Tags: tor, anonymity

I dont understand this as you are either way going through multiple places in the world before you connect to the website or however it works. Does it really matter if i use an onion alternative link?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you access a clearnet site through tor, the connection must be routed through a tor exit node.  Exit nodes are often overloaded, so the connection can be slow.  Accessing the hidden service site through its .onion address avoids this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons, depending on why you're using Tor and what your goal with the site in question is. Broadly, some likely ones in no particular order:

- Performance. As [@mti2935 mentioned](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/274732/what-is-the-point-of-using-onion-alternatives-for-clearnet-websites-when-using-t#comment572461_274732), Tor exit nodes see a ton of traffic, and are often slow. While there's no guarantee that staying within the Tor network will avoid an overloaded node, it's virtually a guarantee that you'll hit one exiting the network.
- You're using Tor to evade detection by adversaries who are monitoring your connection and may also be monitoring exit nodes, and want to make it harder to correlate your traffic into Tor with your traffic to the target site.
- The site in question behaves differently depending on whether the traffic comes over Tor or not (possibly just as a matter of "does geolocation stuff that is incorrect for your exit node's location" or similar where it's a matter of convenience/content not being in an unexpected language, possibly meaningful differences in how much tracking it attempts to perform) and you prefer the version of the site you get with Tor.
- There are legal liabilities associated with using the site, and you don't want to get the exit node operator in trouble.

Obviously, there could be others. People also might just not have a good reason; maybe the site is blocked in their home country and they *could* just use Tor or another proxy/VPN to tunnel out but the only address they were given was the onion link. Maybe they don't even know that Tor can be used to access public sites, it's just "the tool they use to visit banned sites" and they always use onion links. Additionally, there might be multiple reasons which are strong enough in combination, or some such thing.